# Classic ASP do loop only returning 1 result

Tags: asp-classic

Can someone please take a look at my loop? The SQL statement returns 5 results in SQL Management Studio but only 1 on the page. I'm guessing it's my loop but I can't see why. It's probably something obvious.

```
function getpayments()  

dim sqlpay, rspay, oStr, paystat

sqlpay = (Returns 5 results) 
sqlexecute sqlpay, rspay
if not rspay.eof then
    do until rspay.eof
        paystat = rspay("Status")
        oStr = "<tr><td>" & sh(rspay("Date")) & "</td><td>" & sh(rspay("TypeName")) & "</td>"
            if (paystat = "Cheque Sent") or (paystat = "Transfer Made") or (paystat = "Cash Paid") or (paystat = "BACS Cleared") or (paystat = "Transfer Cleared") or (paystat = "BACS Sent") or (paystat = "Cash Cleared") or (paystat = "Cheque Cleared") then
                oStr = oStr & "<td><span class=""label label-success"">Complete</span></td>"
            elseif (paystat = "Committed") or (paystat = "On Hold") then
                oStr = oStr & "<td><span class=""label label-warning"">Pending</span></td>"
            else
                oStr = oStr & "<td><span class=""label label-danger"">Not Approved</span></td>"
            end if
        oStr = oStr & "<td>&pound;" & sh(rspay("Amount")) & "</td></tr>"
        rspay.MoveNext
    Loop
else
    oStr = "<tr><td>No payments found</td></tr>"
    rspay.close
end if
set rspay = nothing

getpayments = oStr

end function
```

Comment: Nothing unusual here. What does `sqlexecute` do?

Comment: Just runs the sql, this is driving me mad.

Comment: I agree with @Bond its likely the `sqlexecute()` function can you post the code and the SQL you pass to it *(`sqlpay`)*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see it now. You're probably getting your 5 records but your `oStr` string is being assigned a value on each iteration, overwriting the previous value. So you're probably only getting your *last* record returned from this function.

```vb
oStr = "<tr><td>" & sh(rspay("Date"))...  ' This is overwriting any previous value
```

So you're really not concatenating your records here because it's being "reset" with each new record. Just change it to:

```
oStr = oStr & "<tr><td>" & sh(rspay("Date"))...
```

Comment: Good catch missed that.